# ¿Conocen alguna función en PHP que pueda retornar los códigos estado HTTP?

Tags: php, php7, http, https

estoy tratando de conseguir el código estado HTTP de un servidor externo pero no pude encontrar alguna función con PHP que me permita hacerlo, lo que necesito es agregar una URL o IP y que la función retorne el codigo de estado HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes la funcion **http_response_code**

y aqui te dejo un enlace al manual de php, donde obtendras mas informacion de como manipular el protocolo http en php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/context.http.php